# how to add index of item to a navigation page in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

```
private void my_listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)   
{            
    try
    {
        FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
        SampleData item = (SampleData)element.DataContext;
        int index = dataSource.IndexOf(item);
        string s = "/Page"+index;
        s +=".xaml";
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("s", UriKind.Relative));
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry..please try again..");
    }
}
```

This is the part of the code. What is wrong in this? It goes to the navigation failed function when I click on an item in the list box. I want to get the item pressed and add it to the navigation page. Could you help please?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes around "s":

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(s, UriKind.Relative));
```

If you put `s`, then you're using the contents of the variable `s`. If you use `"s"`, then you're creating a new string containing the literal value `s`.

Comment: not working even after that..its again showing the same function which defines navigation failed..

Comment: Then your page probably doesn't exist. Check the contents of the `s` variable just before the call to `NavigationService.Navigate`, then make sure that you have a XAML page at the same location.

Comment: when i code it as                                   `NavigationService.Navigate(newUri("Page1.xaml",UriKind.Relative));`   its working fine

Comment: You should check the value of the `index` variable, it's most likely not `1`.

Comment: yes..my index value is displaying -1 no matter what item i press..what should i do to rectify it?

Comment: `IndexOf` returns -1 when the element cannot be found. As to know why `item` isn't inside of `dataSource`, only you can tell.

Comment: what is the eventhandler for listbox?

Comment: What you're probably trying to do is `dataSource.IndexOf(e.AddedItems[0]);`

Comment: public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    { public MainPage()
        {InitializeComponent();
            this.my_listbox.ItemsSource = dataSource;}
        private void my_listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {/..above mentioned code../   }
     }  public class SampleData { public string Topic { get; set; }}
  List<SampleData> dataSource = new List<SampleData>
            { new SampleData(){Topic="Introduction" },}; }     whats wrong now?? i dont know how to add a event handler.wen i press an item i should navigate to selectionchanged right?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the way you are getting index from datasource I feel, may be you are trying to pass a QueryString argument to your page..if so, try like this

```
string s = "/Page.xaml?index=" + index;
```

and in your destination page load, read that argument

```
string qryArgVal = "";
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("index", out qryArgVal);
```

Comment: nope am not passing any value.i wanted to attach the index value to the navigation page.

Answer (score 0):

i found myself the answer.in a listbox the simplest way of getting the index is `int k = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;` and now your k will have the index value